# Initializing a socket object

Tags: python, sockets, networking

When setting up a socket objects, I use:

```
socket.socket()
```

Which, written more verbosely (also what it defaults to) is:

```
socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

A few questions on this:

`socket.AF_INET` allows me to pass to pass a host/port, that is, an ipv4 address. Why is the convention to call it `AF_INET` (and not, for example, `socket.IPV4`. What does that stand for?

What is `SOCK_STREAM`? Does this just mean it's going to accept an `HTTP` request, or something else? Also, what would be the difference between using `SOCK_STREAM` and `SOCK_RAW` ?

Comment: For the same reason WW1 was called The Great War at first. Nobody knew at the time there would be a second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name `AF_INET` was copied from Unix, it's short for "InterNET". The abbreviation was created many years before IPv6 was designed, there was just one Internet protocol, so the idea of calling it `IPV4` didn't come into the designer's minds.

`AF` stands for "Address Family", meaning that the protocol uses Internet addresses. There's also `PF`, which stands for "Protocol Family". At the time this was designed, there was the idea that there might be multiple protocols that use the same form of addressing, so they separated these concepts, but in practice they turned out to be one-to-one, so the distinction faded away (all the AF_xxx constants have the same values as the corresponding PF_xxx constants).

`SOCK_STREAM` means that the socket transfers a stream of bytes. The alternative is `SOCK_DGRAM`, which transfers messages as distinct units called "datagrams".

Answer (score 0):

All names are "borrowed" from [[man7]: SOCKET(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) (`man socket`).

What do different abbreviations stand for:

- *AF_* - Address Family
- *_INET* - Internet (*IPv4* - existing at that time). Full *spec*: [[IETF.Tools]: INTERNET PROTOCOL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791)
- *SOCK_* - Socket
- *_DGRAM* - Connectionless datagram (usually *UDP* protocol)
- *_STREAM* - Connection byte stream (usually *TCP* protocol)
- *_RAW* - Raw ("unprocessed") network protocol (or raw sockets: [[man7]: RAW(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html))